# Как удалить строку в sqlite которую задаю переменной

Tags: python, sqlite

интересует как можно удалить именно ту строку, которую я сам задам переменной?

Это мой неверный код

```css
a = input()
cur.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name=a;")
conn.commit()
```

Думал можно сделать вот таким способом, но данные я ввожу, а он все равно не удаляет

```css
a = input()
cur.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id= '{a}'")
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тому, что Ваш код не работет есть две причины:

#### Первая:

```py
# В этом варианте ошибка состоит в том, что вы забыли сделать строку форматируемой
a = input()
cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id= '{a}'")
#           ^^
conn.commit()
```

> В вашем варианте получается, что имя пользователя = `{a}`, а я сомневаюсь, что пользователь с таким именем есть у Вас в БД

#### Вторая:

```py
# Так как делаете Вы, делать вообще не рекомендуется.
# Правильно будет так:
a = input()
cur.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", [a])
conn.commit()
```